# How to have text of 2 different colors with Material-UI text field?

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to add an autocomplete feature in my project and I'd like the possible autocomplete data to be a greyed out, unselectable and without affecting the user typing.

If I could get the placeholder to be always visible that could work.
I tried setting the `value` prop of `TextField` to an `JSX.Element` but it only accepts primitive types. Fortunately I am using monospace fonts.

What are my options?

A div that is always visible and on-top?
2 text field next to each other with no padding or margin?
Somehow make the placeholder always visible?

Forced example (ignore the cursor)
[image]

Comment: Just here to check how BB has evolved and what you had in mind. seeing the v 1.4* now and how v.0.53 back then, good job!